# AEM - Store the HTML version of the page in HTML

Tags: aem

I have a very specific use case for AEM so maybe you have a solution or an alternative.

I'd need to be able to store the html version of the page in JCR (as it is stored in the dispatcher) so that I would be able to retrieve it in a separate API call from a different system.

Have you had this problem before, or do you have any idea how that could be achieved?

Many thanks

Comment: Cant you just request it directly from publisher? Or even better, dispatcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest not to have the .html page stored inside the AEM instance as that is not core objectives of the AEM as content management system. You should use your dispatcher instance (cached files) and try to keep it on an FTP server and share the file URL with different instances as a data.

Again, please note that AEM instances are very sensitive and should mainly focus on the pages/components. In this case, you are storing the page which is generated out of the components and every time when they generated or modified you need to update this again. it will be a burden. Hence, I am suggesting to take it from the dispatcher instance which will happen as part of the publishing process.

Let me know if you have any other thoughts.